# How can I apply the strategy pattern to a set of derived classes?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have been learning about the strategy pattern. I have seen it as a technique that allows you to write extra code for an existing class with minimal changes to the original class.

I would like to apply this technique in my code, but my code has a set of derived classes that I want to implement strategies for.

To make a concrete example. Let's say I have an empty Shape class, and two subclasses Rectangle (int width, int height) and Circle (int radius).

I would like to implement a serialization strategy pattern that can write a Shape out as a simple TOML file.

I can do it like this for a single shape:

```
class Rectangle; 

class SerializerStrategy {
public:
  virtual std::string serialize(const Rectangle& rectangle) = 0;
};

class TomlSerializer : public SerializerStrategy {
public:
  std::string serialize(const Rectangle& rectangle) override {
    return "[Rectangle]\n"
           "width = " + std::to_string(rectangle.getWidth()) + "\n"
           "height = " + std::to_string(rectangle.getHeight());
  }
};
```

But I cannot find any solution which would enable me to, for example, iterate over a vector of Shapes that may be rectangles or circles and serialize each one.

I have tried reading through a lot of related questions on stack overflow. I've written my own simplified example code out as an experiment. I have watched video lectures on C++. I have asked claude AI for example code. I didn't find a solution from any of these attempts.

Comment: i think the visitor pattern is more feasible here, deducing that the shape is a rectangle is not simply handled by the strategy pattern.

Comment: The strategy pattern for serializing can work if you're serializing to different media and need different functionality for them (e.g. file, network, raw disk). It doesn't work to serialize different classes because that depends too much on the data in the classes.

Comment: Is there no way to combine visitor and strategy?

I also though visitor was more relevant when your data structure was recursive

Answer (score 1):

The strategy solves the problem of having different output formats like Toml, Json, etc. However, you'd still need to have separate functions for serializing a circle versus a rectangle. One way to do this is to add a separate serialize overload for a circle inside your SerializerStrategy:

```cpp
class SerializerStrategy {
public:
  virtual std::string serialize(const Rectangle& rectangle) = 0;
  virtual std::string serialize(const Circle& circle) = 0;
};
```

Then you can add a `serialize` method to the Shape class that accepts a `SerializerStrategy`:

```cpp
class Shape {
  //...
  virtual std::string serialize(const SerializerStrategy& strategy) = 0;
}
```

which you can then override like this:

```
std::string Rectangle::serialize(const SerializerStrategy& strategy) {
  return strategy.serialize(*this); // Use the Rectangle overload
}
std::string Circle::serialize(const SerializerStrategy& strategy) {
  return strategy.serialize(*this); // Use the Circle overload
}
```

Comment: this is not the strategy pattern, this is the visitor pattern, for the strategy pattern your function has to take a `Shape&` and work with it somehow.

Comment: Nope, that is not necessary for a class to be a strategy. See: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy. Indeed, this strategy contains more algorithms than one, but that is allowed according to the documentation. A visitor pattern would look different. It would introduce a class called ShapeVisitor. Then introduce visit functions there and then one would implement a concrete ShapeVisitor that contains the serialization logic. Note that this would mean introducing the additioinal class `ShapeVisitor`. We do not need it here since there is only one type of visiting we do: serializing.

Comment: Your answer shows [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch#Double_dispatch_in_C++).